# TargetParameterCountException: Parameter count mismatch on invoke - delegate

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I have the following code (removed unrelated)

```
//top of class declaration
private delegate void UpdateFormElements(string status, bool addEmptyRow);

//inside a function in my class
if(lboImages.InvokeRequired)
{
   lboImages.Invoke((UpdateFormElements)delegate { UpdateListBox("some text", true); });
}

private void UpdateListBox(string line, bool addEmptyRow)
{
    lboImages.Items.Add(line);
    if (addEmptyRow)
    {
        lboImages.Items.Add("");
    }
}
```

Basically I'm trying to pass two parameters to the UpdateListBox function to test whether to add an empty line or not to my listbox, but I am getting the error in the title.  I have tried putting the two values in an object[] but it doesn't seem to change anything as I still get the error.

I'm still new to using threads so not really sure where I'm going wrong here.

Comment: It is fine to use an anonymous method, but that's Action, not UpdateFormElements.  Since it doesn't take arguments.  And always strongly favor BeginInvoke over Invoke, it is faster and won't deadlock.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not clear why you're trying to use an anonymous method here. The problem is that you're creating a delegate type with two parameters, but you're not passing arguments (values for those parameters) into `Invoke`.

I suspect you just want:

```
lboImages.Invoke((UpdateFormElements) UpdateListBox, "some text", true));
```

That uses a method group conversion to create an `UpdateFormElements` delegate, and provides it the two arguments it needs.

Alternatively, you could just use a lambda expression:

```
MethodInvoker invoker = () => UpdateListBox(line, addEmptyRow);
lboImages.Invoke(invoker);
```

Comment: Thanks so much!  That fixed it.  I've been fiddling with syntax for over an hour trying to get this to work.